# Powermock, mockStatic of UUID.getRandom works in test class but doesn't in the class tested

Tags: uuid, powermock, mockstatic

Strange case: using Powermock to mock out UUID.getRandom(). This works within the JUnit test class but when the class under test (a Filter, if that matters) calls UUID.getRandom, a unique UUID is produced.

Simple test case

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({UUID.class})
public class MyTest {

    private MyFilter filter;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        //The most convenient way to get a UUID, have also tried creating one manually
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

        mockStatic(UUID.class);

        PowerMockito.when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuid);

        filter = new MyFilter();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyUUID() {

        //This test works
        assertEquals(UUID.randomUUID(), UUID.randomUUID());

    }

    @Test
    public void testFilterUUID() {

        //This test fails
        assertEquals(UUID.randomUUID(), filter.getUUID());
    }
}
```

Simple class being tested

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    public UUID getUUID() {

        return UUID.randomUUID();
    }
}
```

Pretty simple stuff, have done mocking like this before, just can't figure out why this case doesn't work.

Using Powermock version 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `UUID` falls under the ["*system classes*" category](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System), so you need to prepare for test the class calling `UUID.randomUUID()`([related github issue](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/374))., thus changing to `@PrepareForTest({MyFilter.class})` should fix things. The following works as expected with JUnit 4.4 & Powermock 1.5, as well as JUnit 4.12 and Powermock 1.7.3:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyFilter.class)
public class MyTest {

    private MyFilter filter;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        //The most convenient way to get a UUID, have also tried creating one manually
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        mockStatic(UUID.class);
        PowerMockito.when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuid);
        filter = new MyFilter();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyUUID() {
        //This test works
        assertEquals(UUID.randomUUID(), UUID.randomUUID());

    }

    @Test
    public void testFilterUUID() {
        //This test fails
        assertEquals(UUID.randomUUID(), filter.getUUID());
    }
}
```

Comment: That is it! Thank you very much, I spent hours on this.

Comment: This only works if you have only one test. If you have multiple tests, you would get:
`For java.util.UUID, static mocking is already registered in the current thread`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution that is mentioned here won't work if you have multiple tests that tries to `mockStatic` before the tests, since `mockStatic` method from `Mockito` does not automatically close after the test.

I wrote the below solution which handles multiple tests by using `PowerMockito.mockStatic` instead of `Mockito.mockStatic`:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyFilter.class, UUID.class})
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "javax.management.*"})
public class MyTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(UUID.class);
        PowerMockito.when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenAnswer((invocation) -> uuid);

        filter = new MyFilter();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyUUID() {
        //This test works
        assertEquals(UUID.randomUUID(), UUID.randomUUID());

    }

    @Test
    public void testFilterUUID() {
        //This test fails
        assertEquals(UUID.randomUUID(), filter.getUUID());
    }
}
```

NOTE to how `mockStatic` is used from `PowerMockito` library not the `Mockito`.